# What is the best string message format for AWS SQS?

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

Maybe it is a dumb question but just started to work on Aws Sqs; I want to sent a message to the queue(normal queue/not FIFO), I have a customerDto which has first name,last name and balanceAmount. I want to send these information in a single message and then in another method I want to get that message.

In which format I can send the message? Just send them all together with a custom sign like "+" and then parsing "+" to space character?.. Or Which way is good for listener method to parse properly ?

```
public class CustomerDto {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Name of the user", required = true)
    private String firstName;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Last name of the user", required = true)
    private String lastName;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Balance", required = true)
    private Long accountBalance;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common thing, I believe, would be to serialize your data into a JSON string. It's simple, and every language has a way of dealing with it already.

Comment: can you give an example how to serialize a json object with these 3 property? im already getting dto object as parameter to the method, should I convert it to a normal object first then serialize ?

Comment: I don't know what language you are in, so I can't really show you an example. As long as the "dto" object has all the properties you want to pass along I don't see why you couldn't just serialize that.

Comment: It looks like you're using Java, you might use Jackson library to handle JSON serialization

Comment: Why not MsgPack? Protobuf? Thrift? Avro? SmileJSON?